# Standard classes - bug wih landscape option?

Tags: two-column, landscape

please look at the following file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,landscape,twocolumn]{book}

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

ABCD

\end{document}
```

When I compile this without hyperref the landscape option is ignored. The second column ist cut off.

When I add hyperref everything works correctly.

Has anyone an idea what is wrong here? (I use MikTeX 2.9 64 bit und TeXnicCenter 2.02.)

Comment: This does not happen when I use scrbook instead....

Comment: You mean that the dimensions of the PDF pages are not automatically set, don’t you?

Comment: There's no bug, and there's no other problem. Just load the `showframe` (or `rotating`) package to determine that the page dimensions are the correct ones for landscape mode.

Comment: I am not sure but do the standard classes have the landscape option at all?

Comment: @ Gustavo Mezzetti: You are right. What is happening here? The columns are fitted to the landscape option but the page dimensions are not. So the second column ist always cut off.

Comment: This behavior is known.  Strictly speaking, it could be considered a bug of the standard classes, but keep in mind that they were conceived many years ago, when the only available output format was DVI…

Comment: OK, thank you... But why does the Problem disappear when I load hyperref or showframe?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - The `landscape` option just interchanges the values of `\textwidth` and `\textheight`: `\DeclareOption{landscape}{{\setlength\@tempdima{\paperheight}\setlength\paperheight{\paperwidth}\setlength\paperwidth{\@tempdima}}`.

Comment: Because those packages (and others) take care of setting up properly the PDF dimension, when they recognize that PDF output is being generated.  You can make up for the issue with `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}`, too.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti - Specifying `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}` does the trick for pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX; for LuaLaTeX -- at least for the version that's still distributed with MacTeX2016 -- it's necessary to load the package `luatex85` as well.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I think you misspelled "documented feature" !

Answer (score 7):

The `landscape` option is not ignored, it works as advertised and swaps `\paperheight` and `\paperwidth`, and sets up `\textwidth` and `\textheight` for landscape orientation.

In classic TeX, there is no notion of controlling the media that you print on, so the size of the text block is the only meaning for `landscape` if you want the page rotated 90 degrees then you should just use your hands to move the paper it is printed on.

However times move on... and most dvi drivers and pdf back ends do now have a way of specifying the size and orientation of the media but latex can only communicate that to the back end if a driver-specific package is used, `graphics`, `hyperref`, `geometry` for example all have driver options such as `dvips` or `pdftex` and also have heuristics to guess a default driver.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is well known: since they were designed when the only available output format was DVI, the standard classes don’t bother, when PDF output is being generated, to set the PDF page dimension `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight`, so to keep them “in sync” with the internal LaTeX2e dimensions `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight`.  Modern PDF-aware packages, on the other hand, correct this behavior.  Instead of `hyperref`, you could load the `geometry` package, perhaps with the option `pass`, which avoid tampering with the text dimensions and margins.  Or, if you want to avoid packages altogether, you could also include a hand-made pacth in your source file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,landscape,twocolumn]{book}

% \usepackage[pass]{geometry}
% \usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\ifx \pdfoutput \@undefined \else
    \ifnum \pdfoutput > 0
        \AtBeginDocument{%
            \pdfpagewidth  \paperwidth
            \pdfpageheight \paperheight
        }
    \fi
\fi

\makeatother



\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

ABCD\newpage Efgh.

\end{document}
```

## Addition

I’ve managed to recover a tiny package I wrote several years ago exactly for this problem.  It was named `pdftexpatch`; here’s the code:

```
%%-------------  Identification  -------------%%

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1998/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{pdftexpatch}[2009/03/05 v.0.02]

%%--------------  Initial Code  --------------%%

% No initial code.

%%---------  Declaration of Options  ---------%%

% No options.

%%-----------  Options Processing  -----------%%

% No options.

%%----------------  Main Code  ---------------%%

\ifx \pdfoutput \@undefined \else
    \ifnum \pdfoutput > 0
        \AtBeginDocument{%
            \pdfpagewidth  \paperwidth
            \pdfpageheight \paperheight
        }
    \fi
\fi

%%---------------  End of Code  --------------%%

\endinput
```

With this package installed, you can just say

```
\usepackage{pdftexpatch}
```

in your main source file, instead of inserting every time the hand-made patch.

Comment: actually it was more a deliberate choice rather than being modern or not. The graphics packages (which do set the media dimensions) were released within months of the first test releases of 2e) but by choice we kept the core code driver independent (there were a lot more drivers with a lot more varied options then than now)

Comment: This works for PDFLaTeX but not for LuaLaTeX...

Comment: @user125730 which is more or less exactly why the core latex code did not attempt driver-specific settings (for luatex replace `pdfoutput` by `\outputmode` and `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight` by `\pagewidth` and `\pageheight`. for latex+dvips instead replace the setting of `\pdfpageheight/width` by `\special{papersize=\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight}%` other tex systems require other syntax....

Comment: @user125730: Well, what did you expect from a micro-package named `pdftexpatch`? :-)