# how does geometry package convert all lengths in landscape mode?

Tags: geometry

`landscape` in `documentclass` doesn't make the paper landscaped. That's why I had to use geometry package.

---

**Portrait** mode:
[image: portrait]

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document}
\layout
\end{document}
```

---

**Landscape** mode:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document}
\layout
\end{document}
```

[image: landscape]

---

But how does it convert all lengths (with landscape option only)? In the documentation I only found that it exchange `paperwidth` with `paperheight`. And this is why `paperwidth` is 614pt in portrait mode and `paperheight` is 614pt in landscape mode. And `paperheight` is 794pt in portrait mode and `paperwidth` is 794pt in landscape mode. But it doesn't exchange every widths with every heights. You can see that `textheight` is 550pt in portrait, but `textwidth` is 556pt instead of 550pt in landscape mode. And I searched for 556pt package file and found nothing. It means that they are not given aboslute values. So, how are they calculated? And how many lengths are changed in geometry package with only `landscape`?

Comment: I think you can phrase this question a little better by (i) removing the initial, unrelated reference to a bug; (ii) showing a minimal example with a picture in portrait mode; (iii) showing the same example's output in landscape mode; (iv) asking the question more clearly: "When switching to `landscape` mode with [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry), the paper height and width lengths are switched. Which other lengths (if any) are adjusted and if so, by how much?"

Comment: ...you can use the `layout` package to find out...

Comment: if you look at the source of the `\documentclass` command you will see it does not mention `landscape` at all, so how can it have a bug in `landscape` ?

Comment: see this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357557/standard-classes-bug-wih-landscape-option) @DavidCarlisle

Comment: that is the design of the standard classes, not a bug and  not related to \documentcass other than that inputs it. your comment is like saying an error in your chapter file is an error in \input

Comment: Oh, but it was not my question. I just thought landscape also effects the paper, but it only effects content. That’s why I used geometry package.

Comment: yes but it doesn't make it easy to answer the question if you start it with such a false statement, you might like to edit it. as it is your question appears to be a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/357562/1090 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591067/margin-differences-in-class-a4paper-and-geometry-a4paper/591192#591192

Comment: My question is not about landscape, it is about how geometry converts lengths. It's not duplicate ig.